# Event Sourcing Commands vs Events

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I understand the difference between commands and events but in a lot of cases you end up with redundancy and mapping between 2 classes that are essentially the same (ThingNameUpdateCommand, ThingNameUpdatedEvent). For these simple cases can you / do you use the event also as a command? Do people serialise to a store all commands as well as all events? Just seems to be a little redundant to me.

Answer (score 19):

All lot of this redundancy is for a reason in general and you want to avoid using the same message for two different purposes for a number of reasons:

1. Sourced events must be versioned when they change since they are stored and re-used (deserialized) when you hydrate an aggregate root. It will make things a bit awkward if the class is also being used as a message.
2. Coupling is increased, the same class is now being used by command handlers, the domain model and event handlers now.  De-coupling the command side from the event can simplify life for you down the road.
3. Finally clarity.  Commands are issued in a language that asks something to be done (imperative generally).  Events are representations of what has happened (past-tense generally).  This language gets muddled if you use the same class for both.

In the end these are just data classes, it isn't like this is "hard" code.  There are ways to actually avoid some of the typing for simple scenarios like code-gen.  For example, I know Greg has used XML and XSD transforms to create all the classes needed for a given domain in the past.

I'd say for a lot of simple cases you may want to question if this is really domain (i.e. modeling behavior) or just data.  If it is just data consider not using event sourcing here.  Below is a link to a talk by Udi Dahan about breaking up your domain model so that not all of it requires event-sourcing.  I'm kind of in line with this way of thinking now myself.

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/talk-from-udi-dahan

Answer (score 8):

After working through some examples and especially the Greg Young presentation (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGkaShoyNs) I've come to the conclusion that commands are redundant. They are simply events from your user, they did press that button. You should store these in exactly the same way as other events because it is data you don't know if you will want to use it in a future view. Your user did add and then later remove that item from the basket or at least attempt to. You may later want to use this information to remind the user of this at later date.

Comment: I'm inclining in this direction as well. I read some good points made about that you want your event to contain all the data it needs to do the job, especially when that data can come from external systems that do not have a historical representation. But you can simply apply that good practice to Commands as well. Especially I think if you want to make something very DDD, there shouldn't be a real difference between commands or events. The intent should be clear and historical data outside your domain should be included.

Comment: I'm still of the opinion that commands are redundant. I just call what I do functional event sourcing. A recent blog of mine with ES and F# Elm as a complete system: http://anthonylloyd.github.io/blog/2016/11/27/event-sourcing

Comment: I also think the difference for me is using FP instead of OO. ES maps to FP really well with sum types being a natural extendable event schema. Immutability also fits really well with ES.

Comment: Another reason why I think user commands could just as well be considered events is because I design a UI as having local data that is modified, and those modifications are sent to the backend as commands/events asynchronously and after the fact. You're going to want to assume that goes well and respond appropriately if it didn't. There's no real difference, in other words, I'm currently thinking.

Comment: Check out this project - https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r . It uses both commands and events.